# iTunes Match looping step 1 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-match

I upgraded my MacBook (mid 2010, 13.3in) to Mountain Lion, and ever since then iTunes Match has been stuck on Step 1: Gathering information about your iTunes library. It will fill up about 60% of the progress bar and then either stop or restart step 1 again.

I’ve tried quitting iTunes and reopening it, and also restarting my computer, both to no avail. 

 Is there anything I can do?

 Thanks
EDIT: It finally finished step 1 (after hours of waiting and starting it again when it stopped), but now it stops and has to be manually started again after matching about a thousand tracks.

Comment: How many tracks do you have? On my machine, with over 30 000 tracks and 8GB of RAM, it took over a day and I restarted it several times.

Comment: I only have about 6,000 (55gb). My computer has 4gb RAM and 1tb hard drive (both of which I upgraded from the original 2 ram and 250gb hd)

Comment: changed wifi networks and iTunes Match worked like a charm. It was really slow uploading the songs (90kbs) but other than that it was great. 
I’m not really sure why this worked but… I’m glad it did.

Comment: UPDATE: When I went back to my old WiFi, it stopped working again.